# moveit setup assistant not working

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic, moveit-setup-assistant

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i launch moveit setup assistant i receive the following error.

```
roslaunch moveit_setup_assistant setup_assistant.launch

... logging to /home/kannan/.ros/log/0d1dacec-30cd-11ec-b94d-e82a44ef4c23/roslaunch-kannan-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB-15791.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://kannan-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB:39523/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: melodic
 * /rosversion: 1.14.11

NODES
  /
    moveit_setup_assistant (moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [15805]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 0d1dacec-30cd-11ec-b94d-e82a44ef4c23
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [15816]
started core service [/rosout]
process[moveit_setup_assistant-2]: started with pid [15820]
/opt/ros/melodic/lib/moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant: error while loading shared libraries: libmoveit_kinematics_base.so.1.0.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
================================================================================REQUIRED process [moveit_setup_assistant-2] has died!
process has died [pid 15820, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant __name:=moveit_setup_assistant __log:=/home/kannan/.ros/log/0d1dacec-30cd-11ec-b94d-e82a44ef4c23/moveit_setup_assistant-2.log].
log file: /home/kannan/.ros/log/0d1dacec-30cd-11ec-b94d-e82a44ef4c23/moveit_setup_assistant-2*.log
Initiating shutdown!
================================================================================
[moveit_setup_assistant-2] killing on exit
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388972/moveit-setup-assistant-not-working/) by [vidu98](https://answers.ros.org/users/84866/vidu98/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-10-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-10-19**:
Can you check the contents of the following directory `/opt/ros/melodic/lib/moveit_setup_assistant/`  looks you are missing `libmoveit_kinematics_base.so.1.0.8` file

**Comment by [vidu98](https://answers.ros.org/users/84866/vidu98/) on 2021-10-19**:
hi @osilva, im missing "libmoveit_kinematics_base.so.1.0.8" like you said,how to install that file.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-10-19**:
If you are missing this file, it means `moveit` is not properly installed. I suggest to check your `moveit` installation: https://moveit.ros.org/install/

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-10-19**:
Also do a search of your full drive, it may be installed somewhere else, just to see what happened.

**Comment by [vidu98](https://answers.ros.org/users/84866/vidu98/) on 2021-10-20**:
@osilva i am trying to reinstall moveit, im following "https://moveit.ros.org/install/source/",
when i try to run this command "rosdep install -y --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro ${ROS_DISTRO}" i receive following error ;
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-melodic-ros-controllers-cartesian : Depends: ros-melodic-twist-controller but it is not going to be installed
ros-melodic-twist-controller-dbgsym : Depends: ros-melodic-twist-controller (= 0.1.4-1bionic.20210921.212715) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-melodic-pybind11-catkin] failed.

**Comment by [vidu98](https://answers.ros.org/users/84866/vidu98/) on 2021-10-20**:
when im trying to run "sudo apt --fix-broken install"
i get the following error:
Unpacking ros-melodic-twist-controller (0.1.4-1bionic.20210921.212715) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ros-melodic-twist-controller_0.1.4-1bionic.20210921.212715_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libtwist_controller.so', which is also in package ros-melodic-cob-twist-controller 0.8.12-1bionic.20210921.230048
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/ros-melodic-twist-controller_0.1.4-1bionic.20210921.212715_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-10-20**:
Hi I will respond to this question formally and let's start a new question as more people will get the chance to look at it. Thank you.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-20**:
Don't build MoveIt from source, unless you did that initially to install it.

Just make sure you have no outstanding `apt` updates for any ROS packages.

I would recommend to undo whatever you did for your from-source install of MoveIt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it by using  `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq ros-melodic-cob-cartesian-controller-dbgsym`to force remove the broken package and then uninstall moveit using `sudo apt purge ros-melodic-moveit*` and then reinstalled it.

---

Originally posted by [vidu98](https://answers.ros.org/users/84866/vidu98/) with karma: 23 on 2021-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
/opt/ros/melodic/lib/moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant: error while loading shared libraries: libmoveit_kinematics_base.so.1.0.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The error is pointing to a missing file `libmoveit_kinematics_base.so.1.0.8` in the following directory `/opt/ros/melodic/lib/moveit_setup_assistant/`. To correct check if the file is in the directory, if not then check `moveit` installation. For more information: https://moveit.ros.org/install/

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-10-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1